# I have a query regrding to playing wave file from raw directory from res > raw

Tags: android

i have a query regrding to playing wave file from raw directory from res > raw,
 i have written a code  on button click event here is my code

```
public void buttonOnclick(View v) {         
    try {           
        MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();           
        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sc1malf);
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);          
        mMediaPlayer.start();                   
    } catch(Exception e) {           

    }   
}
```

but this code  is not working on samsung android mobile ,any one correct this code

Comment: Could you post errors-exceptions?

Comment: it could be another part of your code, are you sure buttonOnClick() is executing?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `mMediaPlayer.prepare();` before `start()`.

Comment: `create()` [does that for you](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) if successful.